# Adding a large amount of button controls to a List

Tags: c#, winforms, button

In my program I have 150 buttons. They're all named button1 through button150 as they were initially generated by the WinForms designer. My goal is to add them all to a list for some processing later, and I'd rather not just write in a series of 150 lines saying tabletBtns.Add(whichever).

I tried to use some code from some articles that I found around the web that I don't fully understand. but I get a compilation error.

```
List<Button> tabletBtns = new List<Button>;
for (int i = 0; i >= 150; i++)
{
  var buttonName = string.Format("button{0}", i);
  var button = Controls.Find(buttonName, true);

  if (button != null)
  {
      tabletBtns.Add(button);
  }
}
```

Thanks for your time, I appreciate the help.

Comment: Use `new Button()` to create a button control.

Comment: There is a degree of insanity in manually creating 150 buttons. Isn't there a way to create the buttons dynamically at run-time?

Comment: I agreed with @Enigmativity, Hans Passant. I withdraw.my answer (150 times) out of insanity  (and it’s been answered already)

Comment: List<Button> tabletBtns = new List<Button>, really? Try add () after List<Button>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue list:

- **Compile time error** Controls.Find|() returns an array, since you could have controls with the same name in child user or custom controls. In your case, you could use Find(name,false).First() to get the first one.
- **Runtime error** A List of Girrafes cannot contain an Animal, even if Girraffe is an Animal. In your case Control is Animal and Button is Giraffe. Read about covariance and contravariance.
- **Loop does nothing** You have >= 150 in as a condition in your code. Change to <=. You also start your index at 0 instead of 1.

What you need to do is probably:

```
List<Button> tabletBtns = new List<Button>;
for (int i = 1; i <= 150; i++)
{
    var buttonName = string.Format("button{0}", i);
    var button = Controls[buttonName] as Button; // if the buttons are all on the main canvas or Controls.Find(buttonName, true).First() as Button if they are hosted in some child custom or user controls

    if (button != null)
    {
       tabletBtns.Add(button);
    }
}
```

After discussing and researching with @JohnG off-thread, it appears his solution is faster, if that matters to you. For the name check, perhaps something like this would be a start:

```
var buttonsList = Controls.OfType<Button>().Where(b=> Regex.IsMatch(b.Name, @"^button(?<number>\d+)$")).ToList();
//this does not validate that the number is between 1 and 150, that is for another sleepless night :)
```

An even better option would be to generate and add all buttons from code rather than WinForms designer. Good luck!